# RANGE INTERVAL SQLite

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

```
pd.read_sql_query('''
                SELECT date(payment_date),
                        sum(amount) as total_date,
                      avg(sum(amount)) over (order by date(payment_date)
                         RANGE BETWEEN INTERVAL '2'  day PRECEDING AND INTERVAL  '2' day FOLLOWING) rolling_7_days
                FROM payment
                WHERE payment_date BETWEEN '2005-07-01' AND '2005-09-01'
                GROUP BY date(payment_date)

                ''', conn)
```

I do with sakila.db with sqlite3 and find this problem:

```
 ': near "'2'": syntax error
```

Follow the instruction but not OK. https://support.workiva.com/hc/en-us/articles/360042534732-SQL-date-and-time-functions

Comment: As per my knowledge; `RANGE BETWEEN INTERVAL` is not supported in sqlite for Window functions

Answer (score 0):

As your error message correctly points out as `syntax error`;

`RANGE BETWEEN INTERVAL` is not supported in sqlite for Window functions.

Instead you can use standard SQL syntax using `BETWEEN`

The following shall work for you.

```
pd.read_sql_query('''
SELECT
  date(payment_date),
  sum(amount) as total_date,
  (
    SELECT avg(sum(amount))
    FROM payment p2
    WHERE p2.payment_date BETWEEN date(p.payment_date, '-2 days') AND date(p.payment_date, '+2 days')
  ) as rolling_7_days
FROM payment p
WHERE payment_date BETWEEN '2005-07-01' AND '2005-09-01'
GROUP BY date(payment_date)
''', conn)
```